# How to get a mixed object types resultset from Doctrine2 Single Table Inheritance repository?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

For the following schema:

**Animal**
 - age
 - gender
 - size

**Cat extends Animal**
 - fur_color

**Snake extends Animal**
 - scales_color

**Elephant extends Animal**
 - tusks_size

When I do `$em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Animal')->findAll()` I will recieve a collection on `Animal` objects without their subclass properties.

When I do `$em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Cat')->findAll()` I will recieve the objects with their subclass (Cat) properties, however I will get only **Cat** objects (no snakes or elephants).

### 1) Is there I way to get all the animals, but not as base **Animal** objects, but actually their leaf subclass type?

Eg. for database like this:

Animals table:

```
ID  | discr | age | gender | size | fur_color | scales_color | tusks_size
1   | snake | 2   | male   | 20ft | NULL      | green        | NULL
2   | cat   | 3   | female | 5ft  | red       | NULL         | NULL
3   | eleph | 6   | male   | 99ft | NULL      | NULL         | 40ft.
4   | cat   | 2   | male   | 6ft  | grey      | NULL         | NULL
```

I'd like to recieve a Collection of:

- Snake (id: 1, age: 2, gender: male, size: 20ft, scales_color: green)
- Cat (id: 2, age: 3, gender: female, size: 5ft, fur_color: red)
- Elephant (id: 3, age: 6, gender: female, size: 99ft, tusks_Size: 40ft.)
- Cat (id: 4, age: 2, gender: male, fur_color: grey)

### 2) If it's not possible with STI... is it possible with Class Table Inheritance?

Comment: You could get a collection of `Animal` objects and check for type using `instanceof` operator when you loop through the collection

Comment: I'm somehow able to do exactly this with STI. I get entities of different types in the collection returned.

Comment: Yep to what what @Bez said.  STI will do the trick.  Check your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it seems I had some error in my configuration. Recreating the bundle and writing the entities again fixed the problem as @Bez and @Cerad suggested.